# Having a hard time with Ruby on Rails on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rubygems, cygwin

I've challenged myself to try and learn Ruby on Rails, and develop a basic bootstrapped site. I come from Java, if that helps.

I've followed multiple tutorials, and watched lots of videos, but I am having quite a hard time getting started with Ruby on Rails.

Details:

- I am NOT using RVM.
- I am using Cygwin on a 64 bit Windows 7.
- I have all the packages required for Ruby on Rails.
- I have removed (or at least tried) all other places where Rubygems, Rruby, and Rails are, so it should all be in Cygwin.
- When I type `which ruby` in Cygwin, I get `/usr/bin/Ruby`.
- When I type `which rails`, I get `/usr/bin/rails`.
- I have no idea how to get which RubyGems I'm using, mainly because gems and what-not are completely alien to me right now, I haven't gotten that far with the tutorials yet.

When I do `rails -v` or `rails server`, I get this error:

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3-ruby (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Try running `bundle install`.
```

When I do `bundle install` or `bundle update`, I get an error which I can't seem to find anyone else getting:

```
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:253:in `fetch_all_remote_specs': undefined method `list' for #<Gem::SpecFetcher:0x00000600716118> (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `block in remote_specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:231:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:231:in `remote_specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:176:in `block (2 levels) in index'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:175:in `block in index'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/index.rb:7:in `build'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `index'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:168:in `resolve'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:107:in `specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:102:in `resolve_remotely!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:43:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

        I'm fine with installing RVM, though when I do, I'm afraid I'll run into incompatibilities because I'm doing this from Cygwin, and I messed this all up two days ago, I finally got it to get this far.
```

The tutorials I'm using are:

- http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book
- A mix of YouTube videos.

Also, I was reading how Rails uses SQLLite for local database testing. Is this going to affect my ability to use Mongo? I recently learned how to use it, and already began using it for a little project I'm working on to log things.

Comment: SQLite is just the default in Rails because all you need is to install the SQLite gem and it just works. It's a single file DB that doesn't need a DB server process running. It's very handy for quickly developing with a DB. I would eventually get Postgres running for bigger projects. I don't think any of this should interfere with Mongo but I don't know a lot about Mongo.

Comment: Please upload your Gemfile. I have a hunch that some gems that are required might be missing. Even if that's not true, it will help.

Comment: Just use the ruby installer: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/, grab the mingw developer kit so you can compile native code as needed, and you'll be ready. I don't know why you're trying with Cygwin.

Comment: Your SQLite question is pretty off-topic for your main question. I'd  recommend asking that separately, but, I suspect it will only solicit opinions, not facts.

Comment: @ArpitChauhan http://pastebin.com/t9QBBujx This is my current Gemfile for first_app. The tutorial I saw told me to change a lot of things, but that did nothing but introduce many errors.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Because I'm very new to this all. RubyInstaller installed an older version, and I couldn't update it, it also made Cygwin upset when it had multiple instances of Ruby on Rails. What is Mingw?

Comment: You must have selected the wrong download. The current version 2.0.0-p247 is available as an installer. It's really quite simple. You may have messed up your environment (you'll probably need to look at your environment paths). Do not install it under cygwin. You shouldn't need it. Once you have it working, follow the instructions on that same page for building native extensions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd like to answer my own question I posted a while ago. It's been a while, but I did eventually give up with Windows and just dual boot with Ubuntu. Currently I use a Macbook. I must say, it's much easier to play with Ruby and Rails with a linux based OS.

Answer (score 4):

Any particular reason for going with Cygwin? It's not the answer you probably want, but a much easier way would either be using [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/en) if you really need to be on Windows. The other free and useful option is to download [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), install it, and then install a copy of Linux. Linux Mint is a really easy distro, or the old standby Ubnuntu.

Comment: I'd go with a VM running Ubuntu or Mint if I had to use Windows. Having the true OS underneath the development environment is a major plus once you're trying to install drivers and such. And, developing on a full open-source system is one of the better guarantees that other open-source things will work together.

Comment: Well, I did try Rails Installer, but it installed a different version, and then I simply was not able to follow the tutorial. @the I would use Ubuntu, in fact I love it, but the thing is that I am not able to as I got a new harddrive and am not allowed to modify it. Is there a way to fix my current set up? I'm very new to all this, and have 0 idea of what is going on right now.

Comment: If you can install software, you can run VMs under VirtualBox. It's just a program. The "drives" in the VM are just large files that sit on your windows drive. No repartitioning if that's what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I found rails on Windows to be unusably slow + you have the problem of not targeting your production environment.

A VM will be a lot easier and faster.

Comment: Yes, I also recommend to run VM.
Just start Ubuntu Server edition without X Window (so that the memory usage can be minimized).
Then, do SSH from Windows.
As for editing code, you can setup Shared Folder so that you can edit using any text editor in Windows.